# Global variable isn't holding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, boolean

This should be a really easy "derp" question, but here it is:

I'm trying to set up a global variable in a JS file so that I can control when an action triggers. In my case, I want `okBoxCall` to only be called if `firstTime` is true. I have `firstTime` set to true initially, then I change it to false afterwards. My code is NOT working as it should however, as it still calls up `okBoxCall` more than once.

```
var Dialog;
var HUDWindow;
var smartPhone;
var firstTime = true;


$(document).ready(function(){
   smartPhone = new SmartPhone();
   initDialog();
   initHUDWindow(); 

   if(firstTime == true)
   {
       okBoxCall("Tutorial", "Welcome to McLarin Energy!");
       firstTime = false;
   }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Obviously `firstTime` is not holding its change to false...

**EDIT** Forgot to mention that this is for a 3D game, not web pages. Cookies are not used.

Comment: This code only fires on page load there should be no way for it to fire more than once a page load.  Do you mean you want it to be persistent over multiple page-views so it is only shown the first time some one visits the page?  You would need to use cookies or  DOM storage for that, `firstTime` is reinitialized to `true` every time this page is loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to check whether this is the first time the user opens a page and open a tutorial if it is?

It is not possible the way you want to do it. Every time your page is loaded your script is evaluated again. So this means a variable `firstTime` is created and it is set to `true`. What you need is some persistent storage on the client to store whether it is the first time or not. You will need to set a [cookie](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) or call the [`localStorage` API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) if you don't bother disregarding older browsers.

Comment: It's not a page though, I'm working on a 3D game. We don't use cookies, but we do database. Anyways thanks for the info

Comment: Doesn't matter what you use. As long as it's persisted outside of your javascript (It's a game on a page :D)

Comment: @Briz it doesn't matter if it's a game, because it's a game *in* a web page, so it follows the same rules as a regular page.

Answer (score 3):

Your function should only be called once due to $(document).ready(...).  So, I'm guessing you're reloading the page to get the alert to display again and again...

Maybe you should be looking at using cookies, not just a plain old JS variable..?

Answer (score 1):

What is okBoxCall doing? If you have any error in okBoxCall firstTime = false will not be executed. Set the value before you call okBoxCall.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   smartPhone = new SmartPhone();
   initDialog();
   initHUDWindow(); 

   if(firstTime == true)
   {
       firstTime = false;
       okBoxCall("Tutorial", "Welcome to McLarin Energy!");

   }
});
```

Comment: I thought Javascript didn't stop execution when it encounters an error.